# Number of type $A_{n-1}$ sub-systems of root system $A_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, lie-algebras, root-systems

If I am not mistaken, it should be true that a type $A_n$ root system contains $n+1$ different sub-systems of type $A_{n-1}$. In my geometric application these do appear quite naturally, but is there an easy algebraic way to see this?

Comment: It's easy to see from the extended Dynkin diagram that when you start with a set of simple roots, plus the negative of the highest root, and then leave out any pair of non-orthogonal simple roots (in the diagram: a pair of connected vertices), then you get a basis of a subsystem of type $A_{n-1}$, and these give $n+1$ distinct such subsystems. I do not see right away why these would be *all* choices (although I do see for $n=2,3$ that they are).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg This is very nice, thx! I havent heard of 'extended Dynkin Diagram' outside of affine Lie algebras.. Do I understand you correctly that it is obtained by simply adding the negative of the highest root? Is the "negative of" part a convention?

Comment: Oh it seems like what you are describing IS the affine root system...